# Unable to take a screenshot when my test-case fail

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot

```
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome != ResultState.Success)
{
    string dirPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\..\", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)Driver).GetScreenshot();
    screenshot.SaveAsFile($"{dirPath}\\Screenshots\\{TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName}.png", 
ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
}

Driver.Quit();
}
```

I trying to take a screenshot in case my TestCase fail, but it doesn't happen haha. I think the problem its in this Screenshot method because after this even my Driver. Quit doesn't work? Any another chance to do it or how to fix my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't happen"? Do you get an exception? Have you tried breakpointing on the screenshot code?

Comment: I got to assert a title, let see 'My Title ', I delete a 'M' just because i want my test to fail and make a screenshot, after when i chek expentions show me  correctly that 'M' missing from the title but doesn't make a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You should use ITestResult for taking screenshot for failure please use below code
[image]

[image]

Comment: instead of "TestApp.getInstance().getDriver()" please use driver in your code